# Where is the source code of CallObjectMethod in jni.h

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I searched for the method definition of `CallObjectMethod` method declared in the file `jni.h` in OpenJDK 8. However, I can't find it.

Where is the source code of the method `CallObjectMethod`?

I am studying JDK for the aim of researching. I need to know the JDK entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in [jni.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/hs-dev/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l1645)
by `DEFINE_CALLMETHOD` macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will learn 'DEFINE_CALLMETHOD macro' carefully.